# Codename One - Key binding for "p" is not working?

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to attach Commands to buttons. This method works for 'q' and 'm', but it is not working for 'p' character.

Using '-112' did not solve the problem either. using minus symbol works for arrow keys but not for 'p'.

```java
addKeyListener(113, new CommandA(gameWorld));  // q
addKeyListener(109, new CommandB(gameWorld));  // m
addKeyListener(112, new CommandC(gameWorld)); // p - Not Working
```

pressing 'p' does nothing.

**UPDATE**

Found a workaround...

Answer (score 0):

This won't work for you on the device anyway as most devices are touch devices. The virtual keyboards on such devices don't send these events anyway. The arrow keys send undocumented values which differ a lot and you should "theoretically" use the game key API and not the key API. But again this won't work on the devices most commonly used today.

The characters aren't just numbers. They are literally the character value `(int)'p'`. There is no special treatment for them but it's possible that something in the system is grabbing that specific character as it's commonly associated with a print shortcut.